# I need to create .Zip file in Laravel and my code does not work

Tags: php, laravel, zip, php-ziparchive

this is the 1st time I posted on StackOverflow. I need to create a zip file of multiple images. I've tried Zipper and also ZipArchive and my code still fails.

```php
$zip = new \ZipArchive();
foreach ($students as $student) {
    $download = 'album' . $student->album_id . '.zip';
    if ($zip->open(public_path('albums/' . $student->album_id . '/' . $download), \ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {
        $files = Storage::allFiles('public/albums/' . $student->album_id . '/image_files');
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $zip->addFile($file);
        }
        $zip->close();
    }
}
```

I can assure that all the images exist. I put the images in `Storage/app/public/albums/$student->album_id/image_files/`. Please help me.

Comment: Do you get any error messages ? If so please post them, also does the .zip get created on the disk and what are its contents once created ?

Comment: @IgorIlic i dont get any error messages, that's the problem. It looks like everying works perf but not. The zip files does not get created yet. The zip files conntent is images, as i said in the post above.

Comment: https://imgbbb.com/image/LvXxSi This is the folder structre, where i put the images that need to be zipped

Answer (score 1):

First, you can add an additional step to verify that your file exists by using PHP built in function: **file_exists()**

Most times, if you your files do noT exists, no files will be added to the **zip**, and your code will run without throwing any error but still will not work.

What you're passing to addFile() is not a correct path. addFile() needs an absolute path to where your file is stored. You will need to add this line **$file_path = storage_path("app/{$file}");**

See code below:

```
$zip = new \ZipArchive();
foreach ($students as $student) {
    $download = 'album' . $student->album_id . '.zip';
    if ($zip->open(public_path('albums/' . $student->album_id . '/' . $download), \ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {
        $files = Storage::allFiles('public/albums/' . $student->album_id . '/image_files');
        
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $file_path = storage_path("app/{$file}");
            if (file_exists($file_path)) {
                $zip->addFile($filepath);
            }
        }
        $zip->close();
    }
}
```

Optionally, if you wish to download any of the zipped files, you can return the download response at the end of your code to download:

```
return response()->download(public_path('albums/' . $student->album_id . '/' . $download));
```